# GCC - Linking bass.lib on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, gcc, ubuntu, linker, bass

I wrote an application on Windows using CPP and BASS, and now I have to get it running on Linux (UBUNTU).

```
I am using gcc version 4.5.2.
```

I have bass.lib in my directory from which I try to compile prog.cpp using the following command arguments:

```
gcc prog.cpp -L. -lbass.lib
```

But I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lbass.lib
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I figure that this is a linking error, the compiler is not finding Bass.lib but I have specified as an argument on the command line.

Not sure what to do, any help would be really great.

Comment: Is your `bass.lib` compiled under linux? Naming conventions for libraries in POSIX systems would by `libbass.a` or `libbass.so` (but it is not all about the name...)

Comment: Good point. Let me check it out as I am unsure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

bass.lib sounds like the windows library. You cannot use libraries generated on windows, (likely generated with the MSVC compiler), on linux.

The linux version of the library seems to be named libbass.so , in which case you'd use `-lbass` as the linker argument , and possibly other compiler/linker flags as well depending on where on the system you install the library. The bass.txt in the linux download of libbass have a few notes on what to do on Linux.

Comment: Cheers, I am new to CPP, and thus having a bit of a hard time figuring it out.